# Java.Libraries not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I was Working on IntelliJ. Suddenly, Windows suffered Blue-Screen.

After that, when I reopened IntelliJ, the libraries and packages like  `java.io.BufferedReader`,`java.io.FileReader`, `System.out.println()` were not working and  the IDE was showing an error. Even Eclipse IDE was  affected.

Comment: Reinstall JDK, try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart, add JDK again in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

Set your JAVA_HOME in your system and include in the path variable. Then open command prompt and check java is installed properly or not.

If yes, open IntelliJ and follow the below steps :

- Step 1: Press Alt +Ctrl + Shft + s . You can see project structure window
- Step 2: Click on SKDs just below Platform Settings
- Step 3: Add jdk if jdk is missing.